# Get list of Locale for all stores

Tags: magento2, locale

Is there a way to get the list of all Locale for set up stores?

As you would get Locale for the current store with

```
\Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()->get('Magento\Framework\Locale\Resolver')->getLocale();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From my understanding, we will get the locale values from `core_config_data` table. To get these values, we need to have the path, scope type and scope code:

We will try to get all stores and use scope config object to get the locale values.

```
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager $obj */
$obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();

/** @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface|\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManager $storeManager */
$storeManager = $obj->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$stores = $storeManager->getStores($withDefault = false);

//Get scope config
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface|\Magento\Framework\App\Config $scopeConfig */
$scopeConfig = $obj->get('Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface');

//Locale code
$locale = [];

//Try to get list of locale for all stores;
foreach($stores as $store) {
    $locale[] = $scopeConfig->getValue('general/locale/code', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $store->getStoreId());
}
```

There's a good example how to get locale: `vendor/magento/module-store/Block/Switcher.php`

**EDIT: Avoiding using Object Manager directly.**

Need to inject:

- `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface`
- `Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface`

into the constructor.

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Stores\Model;

class Locale
{
    /**
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $storeManager;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface
     */
    protected $scopeConfig;

    /**
     * Locale constructor.
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig
    )
    {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->scopeConfig = $scopeConfig;
    }

    /**
     * Get list of Locale for all stores
     * @return array
     */
    public function getListLocaleForAllStores()
    {
        //Locale code
        $locale = [];
        $stores = $this->storeManager->getStores($withDefault = false);
        //Try to get list of locale for all stores;
        foreach($stores as $store) {
            $locale[] = $this->scopeConfig->getValue('general/locale/code', \Magento\Store\Model\ScopeInterface::SCOPE_STORE, $store->getStoreId());
        }
        return $locale;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was trying to do. Just fix $storeConfig inside of foreach with $scopeConfig.