# Magento 2 : How to get store information in specific Block

Tags: magento2, override-block

I have Override `\Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View` Block in which i can not get store information.
 I have use `\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager` but it throws following error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught `TypeError`: Argument 12 passed to
>   `Tecksky\Catalog\Block\Product\Specification::__construct()` must
>   implement interface `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface,` array
>   given, called in
>   `/home/sysadmin/share/magento2/project/generated/code/Tecksky/Catalog/Block/Product/Specification/Interceptor.php`
>   on line 14 and defined in
>   `/home/sysadmin/share/magento2/project/app/code/Tecksky/Catalog/Block/Product/Specification.php:12`
>   Stack trace: `#0
>   /home/sysadmin/share/magento2/project/generated/code/Tecksky/Catalog/Block/Product/Specification/Interceptor.php(14):

` 
[image]

How can I use it in this Block file

Comment: Remove generation/generated folder or run setup:di:compile command after adding any dependency in `__constuct` method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly call store manager in your block file, 
Just keep below class in your construct,

```
public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\Url\EncoderInterface $urlEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Json\EncoderInterface $jsonEncoder,
        \Magento\Framework\Stdlib\StringUtils $string,
        \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product $productHelper,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductTypes\ConfigInterface $productTypeConfig,
        \Magento\Framework\Locale\FormatInterface $localeFormat,
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository,
        \Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory $groupCollectionFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct(
            $context,
            $urlEncoder,
            $jsonEncoder,
            $string,
            $productHelper,
            $productTypeConfig,
            $localeFormat,
            $customerSession,
            $productRepository,
            $priceCurrency,
            $data
        );
        $this->groupCollectionFactory = $groupCollectionFactory;        
    }
```

If you needed storemanager you can directly call in your file as below way,

**$this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId()**

Remove generated folder from root and check.

Comment: thanks @rakesh how can i get locale within this?

Comment: what do yo want to get actually using storemanager/

Comment: check link, https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/125388/get-list-of-locale-for-all-stores

Answer (score 3):

Please follow below code you will get all the store information

```
app/code/Chapagain/HelloWorld/Block/HelloWorld.php

<?php
namespace Chapagain\HelloWorld\Block;
class HelloWorld extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{    
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,        
        array $data = []
    )
    {            
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    /**
     * Get store identifier
     *
     * @return  int
     */
    public function getStoreId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    }

    /**
     * Get website identifier
     *
     * @return string|int|null
     */
    public function getWebsiteId()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId();
    }

    /**
     * Get Store code
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStoreCode()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCode();
    }

    /**
     * Get Store name
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStoreName()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getName();
    }

    /**
     * Get current url for store
     *
     * @param bool|string $fromStore Include/Exclude from_store parameter from URL
     * @return string     
     */
    public function getStoreUrl($fromStore = true)
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getCurrentUrl($fromStore);
    }

    /**
     * Check if store is active
     *
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isStoreActive()
    {
        return $this->_storeManager->getStore()->isActive();
    }
}
?>
```

See more functions in vendor/magento/module-store/Model/Store.php.

Now, we print the store information in our template (.phtml) file.

```
echo $block->getStoreId() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreCode() . '<br />';
echo $block->getWebsiteId() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreName() . '<br />';
echo $block->getStoreUrl() . '<br />';
echo $block->isStoreActive() . '<br />';
```

Using Object Manager

```
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        

$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');

echo $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreId() . '<br />';
echo $storeManager->getStore()->getCode() . '<br />';
echo $storeManager->getStore()->getWebsiteId() . '<br />';
echo $storeManager->getStore()->getName() . '<br />';
echo $storeManager->getStore()->getStoreUrl() . '<br />';
```

I hope it's clear to you and will help you.

***Source: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-2-get-store-information-store-id-code-name-url-website-id/***

Answer (score 2):

First, you need  to `do a compilation`.Note ,before doing `compilation,you should delete all files from generate folder`**exclude**  `.htaccess` bcoz rest of all files are re-generate at this folder during compilation.

You don't need inject the class `Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface`.

Then In-herniate class `Magento\Catalog\Block\Product` already has  this class object that can access via `$this->_storeManager` as describe by [Rakesh Jesadiya](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/220797/4564) and [Emipro Technologies Pvt. Ltd](https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/17154/emipro-technologies-pvt-ltd?tab=profile)